# What word can we use to refer to the dome-like street/road and bowl-like street?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, image-identification

[image: Dirt road with a hill][image: Narrow road with a dip]

I already did some research on google regarding this, but it doesn't seem to suit my expectations. I searched with the term "curved road", but it appears that it's just a road with a turning. I'm a bit confused about this.

The photos I have attached here are a dome-like road (white car) and bowl-like road photo (cycling man). Literally, I can't specify the exact shape of these two roads, but this is how they are alike.

Comment: Can you provide an image of the kind of street you are asking about? A road is usually thought of as two-dimensional, so I don't understand how it could be like a dome or bowl. Perhaps you are thinking of a [cul-de-sac](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cul-de-Sac_cropped.jpg)?

Comment: I already added a bowl-like road photo( cycling man) and dome-like road (white car)

Comment: So your dome road goes over a hill, and the bowl road goes through a depression?  One is an uphill followed by a downhill, and the other a downhill followed by an uphill?

Comment: I would call both of those "sloped" roads.

Comment: The first shows an uphill section (from the point of view of the drivers of these cars), the second a dip (from any perspective). I'd avoid 'acclivity' and 'declivity'.

Comment: Broadly, you seem to be trying to describe *convex* and *concave* slopes. What would that leave unclear, please?

No word could ever be used to refer to both dome-like and bowl-like streets, unless it were an non-specific term such as *sloping* which seems fairly clearly not to be what you want.

In two dimensions, the road simply goes where it goes… north or south, east or west. In 3D, it also goes up or down. The difference is immense.

Comment: Are you looking for technical descriptions, such as a highway engineer would use, or "everyday" descriptions such as any regular person would use?

Answer (score 1):

Your distinction twixt "dome" and "bowl" depends solely upon which way one is travelling. They're both just hills.

Answer (score 0):

The west coast, (i.e.) San Francisco, CA, may have their own words, but on the edge where the sun rises we would say:

***"The crest*** (high part) **and** ***the dip*** (low part) **of a** ***hilly*** **road."** (US)

Answer (score -1):

The word “undulating” applies to both, although I think you want an adjective for each type.

Comment: Best I can suggest is a “crest road” and a “sag road”.  You may want to look at this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_design_of_roads

Comment: 'Undulating' applies when there are sequential rises and dips. This may not be true here, particularly in the first case shown.